# ui-view doesn't work when used inside angularjs custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I want to wrap some ui-view elements inside a custom angularjs directive

```
<wrapper>
    <ul>
      <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="well" ui-view="viewA"></div>        
    <div class="well" ui-view="viewB"></div>        
</wrapper>
```

The custom directive does nothing but transcluding the content:

```
myapp.directive('wrapper', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude:true,
        template: '<div class="godWrapper" ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

**See the demo in** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNb2q8KV1u6cgKgTyODo?p=preview)

It seems that ui-view doesn't like to be wrapped as when I remove the wrapper element the demo  works with no problem. Is this a bug in ui-router or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this is a known issue. 
[Issue 774](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/774) and 
[Issue 886](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/886)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but after some diving through angular-ui-router known issues and source code, I found that the problem is with the latest release of angular-ui-router (**0.2.8**) as discussed in [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/774). The following demo is utilising the **0.2.7** release without the mentioned problem. Perhaps this will be useful for someone else

http://plnkr.co/edit/u2LE7gFUGSpAmUNK3fhP?p=preview

Comment: It's ok to answer your own questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer 

`it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged`