# ui.router not working well in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I am working on custom directives in AngularJS and getting help from ***Mark Zamoyta's*** tutorials from ***PluralSight***.

M using UIRouter in angular which is not working well in custom direcives while ngRoute is working well.Here is position of ui-view

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
<div ui-view></div>
```

In Controller i've this code to use routes/states getting from custom directive.

```
$scope.$on('ps-menu-item-selected-event', function (evt, data) {
            $scope.routeString = data.route;
            //$location.path(data.route);
             $state.go(data.route);
            checkWidth();
            broadcastMenuState();
        });
```

Now,I f i use ngroute then it is showing partial/template at right place but if i use ui router it goes out of ui-view ang show partials/templaes but not in between

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

i have thse searches who lead me to downgrading ui router's version but no success.

1.[ui-view doesn't work when used inside angularjs custom directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994715/ui-view-doesnt-work-when-used-inside-angularjs-custom-directives)

2.https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/774

Any Help?????

Comment: could you create a plunkr of it?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$location.path(url)`, you pass in something like `/home/item` into the url, but when you use `$state.go(state)`, you pass in the state name like `home.item`. Make sure you pass the right thing.

Comment: yup m passing the state name because it is going to that state's url but not  inside the custom directive.